# Scrapy FormRequest authentication with user, password plus form_key

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

So I need to parse a set of pages from an authenticated user's point of view and get some values from there...

So I need scrapy to authenticate itself before starting to parse.
In order to do that I understand that I would need to use InitSpider and init_request.

My problem is that in order to authenticate, using a FormRequest, I must send to the form a certain value that is some kind of a session id (form_key) that is generated automatically.

So first, scrapy must access the **self.login_page**, get the value of form_key (like in the xpath bellow), then post the LOGIN FORM to **self.login_post**
The 2 URL's are described bellow in the script section

The HTML containing my form key looks like this:

```
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="2pos7YUekQz6Y9rD">
```

So in order to obtain my form_key value, I did this (updated scrapy script):

```
class MyScript(InitSpider):
    name = "logged-in"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    login_post = 'https://www.example.com/customer/account/loginPost/' 

    def init_request(self):
        """ Called before crawler starts """
        return Request(url=self.login_post, callback=self.login, dont_filter = True)

    def login(self, response):
        """ Generate login request """
        login_page = 'https://www.example.com/customer/account/login/'
        myformkey= self.pax_key(login_page)
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                         formxpath="//div[@class='account-login']/form[@id='login-form']",
                                         formdata={'login[username]':'user',
                                                   'login[password]':'pass',
                                                   'form_key':myformkey                                                   
                                                   },
                                         callback=self.check_login_response)

    def check_login_response(self,response):
        """ Check the response returned by login request to see if we are logged in """
        logging.log(logging.INFO,'... checking login response ...')
        if "Invalid login or password." in response.body:
            logging.log(logging.INFO,'... BAD LOGIN ...')
        else:
            logging.log(logging.INFO, 'GOOD LOGIN... initialize:'+response.url)
            self.initialized()

    def pax_key(self, url):
        data = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
        hxs = Selector(text=data) #HtmlXPath
        lista = hxs.xpath('//input[@type="hidden"][@name="form_key"]/@value').extract()
        logging.log(logging.INFO,lista)
        return lista

    def parse(self, response):
        ...
```

So the problem now is...:

```
INFO: do login...
2015-12-04 21:57:18 [root] INFO: [u'yFVS9fR8Jteuo6Co']
2015-12-04 21:57:19 [root] INFO: http://www.example.com/enable-cookies
2015-12-04 21:57:19 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://www.example.com/enable-cookies> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "d:\Calin\WorkSpace\example-spider\products\spiders\logged-in.py", line 49, in login
    callback=self.check_login_response)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\form.py", line 37, in from_response
    form = _get_form(response, formname, formnumber, formxpath)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\form.py", line 81, in _get_form
    raise ValueError('No <form> element found with %s' % formxpath)
ValueError: No <form> element found with //div[@class='account-login']/form[@id='login-form']
```

So first of all... I have no idea why I get redirected towards the enable-cookies page...

> Spider error processing <GET http://www.example.com/enable-cookies>

I do not tell it to go there... at all.

I assume that is why there is no form there to xpath it... so I get the error in the end.

> ValueError: No <form> element found with
>   //div[@class='account-login']/form[@id='login-form']